# How to set variables to ApachePOI iterated data values

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi

I have two scripts; one with Apache POI to read data from an excel sheet and another for selenium to take the received data from the apache script and use the data for input fields.

here is my apache excel reader script:

```
public class readExcelFinal{
static ArrayList<Double> priceList;
static ArrayList<String> titleList;
static ArrayList<String> descriptionList;
static ArrayList<String> imageLocationList;

public static void processExcelFile(String fileName) throws IOException{
    priceList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    titleList = new ArrayList<String>();        
    descriptionList = new ArrayList<String>();
    imageLocationList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try{
        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
        HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);
        HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(2);
        Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();

        // For each row,
        while(rowIter.hasNext()){
            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();

            // If there's a cell at index 0, it's a price
            if(row.getCell(0) != null)
            priceList.add(row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());

            // If there's a cell at index 1, it's a title
            if(row.getCell(1) != null)
            titleList.add(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());

            // If there's a cell at index 2, it's a description
            if(row.getCell(2) != null)
            descriptionList.add(row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());

            // If there's a cell at index 3, it's an image location
            if(row.getCell(3) != null)
            imageLocationList.add(row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void createTests(){
    // Create an RNG to re-use
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();


    // Iterate through the price list and create tests
    for (Double price : priceList){         

        // For each of title, description, and image location, get a random index into the list and pull the value
        int titleIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(titleList.size());
        String title = titleList.get(titleIndex);           

        int descriptionIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(descriptionList.size());
        String description = descriptionList.get(descriptionIndex);

        int imageLocationListIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(imageLocationList.size());
        String imageLocation = imageLocationList.get(imageLocationListIndex);


        System.out.println("Creating test for Price " + price + "\n\tTitle:\t" + title + "\n\tDesc:\t" + description + "\n\tImg:\t" + imageLocation);

        }
    }

public static String price;
public static String title;
public static String description;
public static String imageLocation;

public void setName(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public static String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public static String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public static String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setImageLocation(String imageLocation) {
    this.imageLocation = imageLocation;
}

public static String getImageLocation() {
    return imageLocation;
}

}
```

and here is my (part) of my selenium script:

```
public class webDriver {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //THIS IS WHERE IM PULLING THE METHOD INTO MY SELENIUM SCRIPT
    readExcelFinal.main(args);



            //EXCELL DATA
            String price = readExcelFinal.getPrice();
            String title = readExcelFinal.getTitle();
            String description = readExcelFinal.getDescription();
            String imageLocation = readExcelFinal.getTitle();

            System.out.println("Creating test for Price " + price + "\n\tTitle:\t" + title + "\n\tDesc:\t" + description + "\n\tImg:\t" + imageLocation);

    // The Firefox driver supports javascript 
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

As you can see in my selenium script, I am using:

```
 System.out.println("Creating test for Price " + price + "\n\tTitle:\t" + title + "\n\tDesc:\t" + description + "\n\tImg:\t" + imageLocation);
```

to quick veiw the data in my console so i don't have to wait for the whole script to run to see whether or not the variables are getting values. I am getting this back in the console:

```
Creating test for Price null
Title:  null
Desc: null
Img: null
```

I am not getting any of the test case data from my script.

Comment: Have a read through [mcve] and eliminate all the variables that are not relevant.

Comment: thanks, Ill take a look

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind `null` values is, you are trying to print the variables `price`, `title`, `description` by calling `getXXX` methods, however, they are not set/assigned values anywhere in the code (e.g. I can't see `setXXX()` being called anywhere) and hence, [default](http://blog.ajduke.in/2012/03/25/variable-initialization-and-default-values/) values are assigned and printed.

By the way, I'd advise you to read through [Java Programming Basics](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138747.html) and difference between [static and non static](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-vs-non-static-methods/) variables/members.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. I had the that section up before I was told it was unecessary.. its back up now

Comment: Now that its back up, what do you think is going on here? I have my setters right there but the values are still not being applied to the variables

Comment: I can't see any setters getting called from anywhere.